# Issues with plugins built with SKPM (Sketch Plugin Manager)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, skpm

Im working on a js plugin for Sketch which utilizes SKPM.  Currently I need to make api calls form the plugin to try uploading files from sketch to my local server. but it appears to be missing basic data objects.  Specifically I have tried the two different pieces of code below in the plugin and have received the following errors.

`FormData undefined`

for the first and

`Can't find variable: URL`

for the second piece of code. The second one uses the npm [upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upload) module.  I will include the package.json as well below both for my asset and parent directory and the manifest.  It appears to be an issue with he packaging.  SKMP also appears to be using webpacks

```
    let formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append("fileupload", context.actionContext.document);
      await fetch('http://localhost/upload', {
      method: "POST", 
      body: formData
    });
```

```
    const upload = new Upload({    
    url: 'https://example.com/upload',
    form: {
      file: context.actionContext.document,
    }});

    upload.on('progress', progress => {
         console.log("progress: ",progress);
       });
       const response =  await upload.upload();
```

package.json

```
{
...
  "engines": {
    "sketch": ">=3.0"
  },
  "skpm": {
    "name": "Export",
    "manifest": "src/manifest.json",
    "main": "plugin.sketchplugin",
    "assets": [
      "assets/**/*"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "skpm-build",
    "watch": "skpm-build --watch",
    "start": "skpm-build --watch --run",
    "postinstall": "cd assets && npm i && cd .. && npm run build && skpm-link"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@skpm/builder": "^0.5.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@skpm/child_process": "^0.2.3",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "upload": "^1.3.2",
    "url": "^0.11.1"
  }
}
```

asset package.json

```
{
  "name": "svgo-export-assets",
  "dependencies": {
    "svgo": "^1.0.4",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "identifier": "com.sketchapp.examples.export",
  "compatibleVersion": 3,
  "bundleVersion": 1,
  "commands": [
    {
      "name": "Export Compress",
      "identifier": "svgo-export",
      "script": "./svgo-export.js",
      "handlers": {
        "actions": {
          "ExportSlices": "onExportSlices"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Export Upload",
      "identifier": "export-upload",
      "script": "./export-upload.js",
      "handlers": {
        "actions": {
          "ExportSlices": "onExport"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Upload Save",
      "identifier": "save-upload",
      "script": "./save-upload.js",
      "handlers": {
        "actions": {
          "DocumentSaved": "onSave"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

I also started with their sample app, and everything else appears to be working.  It appears to be missing WHATWG [support][2].  This plugin is run on a mac app, I cant figure out how to include or get access to these features
```

Update, I have confirmed its due to [missing](https://developer.sketch.com/assistants/javascript-environments) browser apis and modules, any suggestions on how to get modules included or work around this would be welcome